# Android and access to database

Tags: android, sql

I have a question about access to database. I have a database, but I can't see this database in data on my davice. On emulator in data I can see this database but on device data folder is empty. I need to do this because when I want to see database in DDMS perspectiv with emulator, my eclipse is stuck and I must restart.

Comment: you cannot access DB files on your device via DDMS

Comment: so how I can see how looks database on device

Comment: Umm... it should look the same as on the emulator...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android doesn't provide access to its application `data` folders in a device. You can either [root your device](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/Root-Your-Android-Phone,review-1688.html)(which essentially means you give everyone access to all files in your device) or you could move the db to sdcard (if that is a possible option). You can access files in sdcard from adb.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the database using ADB from the terminal (in android tools folder or platform folder). You can't access the database in the device unless you root your device. That's to restrict the application data from being open . (Other application's data).